# Python SocketServer - Purpose of subclassing the BaseRequestHandler

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python and am taking some online security courses.  I must admit, the whole concept of classes is not crystal clear yet so this is probably why I am not fully understanding the concept.  From the python.org site they say:

> Creating a server requires several steps. First, you must create a
>   request handler class by subclassing the BaseRequestHandler class and
>   overriding its handle() method; this method will process incoming
>   requests. Second, you must instantiate one of the server classes,
>   passing it the server’s address and the request handler class.

Can someone explain this better?  Why do you have to create a subclass?  I can understand the power of using classes from a theoretical perspective, I just haven't used them in my test scripts enough yet to get that "ah ha" moment. Here is the script from the course I am taking:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import SocketServer

class EchoHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print "Got Connection from : ", self.client_address
        data = 'dummy'

        while len(data):
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
            print "Client sent: " + data
            self.request.send(data)
        print "client left"

serverAddr = ("0.0.0.0", 9000)

server = SocketServer.TCPServer(serverAddr, EchoHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: This may not be apples to apples, but in concept is this similar to using something like, from threading import Thread vs. import threading?  As I write this I am not sure the analogy is even remotely similar, but is the SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler a form of framework that you leverage in the subclass section to call upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler` is the template that handles under-the-hood processing. But it doesn't actually do anything with the requests.

Subclassing lets you build on that template, adding only the part specific to your implementation, but still keeping all the power of the base. You define `def handle(self)` and do the specific processing of the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

The `BaseRequestHandler` handles the requests for your server. In order to gain access to this class, you need to create a subclass, which (by virtue of being a subclass) will give you access to the various methods of the `BaseRequestHandler` that you need to access in order to handle requests on your server. Take a look at the `BaseRequestHandler` class [from the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/779de7b4909b/Lib/SocketServer.py), and note that the handle method merely has a `pass` as it stands (and so does not do anything):

```
class BaseRequestHandler:

    """Base class for request handler classes.

    This class is instantiated for each request to be handled.  The
    constructor sets the instance variables request, client_address
    and server, and then calls the handle() method.  To implement a
    specific service, all you need to do is to derive a class which
    defines a handle() method.

    The handle() method can find the request as self.request, the
    client address as self.client_address, and the server (in case it
    needs access to per-server information) as self.server.  Since a
    separate instance is created for each request, the handle() method
    can define arbitrary other instance variariables.

    """

    ...

    def handle(self):
        pass

    ...
```

Your code needs to make that `handle` method do something, and you do that by creating a subclass of the `BaseRequestHandler`.